# MVC Using Controller.JavaScript centrally in a Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have some popups defined in Controllers like this

```
Private Function ModalValidation(Message As String) As JavaScriptResult
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
        SB.Append("$('#PopupModal').modal();")
        SB.Append("var vBody = document.getElementById('ModalBodyText');")
        SB.Append("vBody.innerHTML = '" & Message & "';")
        SB.Append("var vTitle = document.getElementById('ModalTitle');")
        SB.Append("vTitle.innerHTML = 'Validation';")
        SB.Append("vTitle.style.color = 'orange';")
        SB.Append("});")
        Return JavaScript(SB.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex, 77, "LoginController")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I would like to find a way to use this code as a public function for all controllers so that we don't have to add it to each page, but don't know how to get a handle on Controller.JavaScript that is not available in a module.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks

============== EDIT ============= ADDED SOME VIEW CODE ===========

```
  <form>
    <div id="PopupModal" Class="modal fade in out">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div Class="modal-content">
                <div Class="modal-header">
                    <Button Class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</Button>
                    <h4 Class="modal-title" id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                </div>
                <div Class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">
                    <h5 id="ModalBodyText"></h5>
                </div>
                <div Class="modal-footer">
                    <Button Class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this jquery code to layout page

Use ViewBag.Message and include in javascript code.

Every page pass to only Message parameter.

```
@{
ViewBag.Message= "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would wire up - I've added a snippet from _Layout.vbhtml